# BigQuery Storage Read API Dependencies

Tags: gradle, google-bigquery, dependency-management, google-bigquery-storage-api

I am working on a project that uses storage read api to retreive data from big query tables, I notice that [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java) suggests to specify both the bom and dependency, like this:

```
implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.22.0')
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquerystorage'
```

In my case, avoiding bom and only specifying

> implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquerystorage:2.41.1'

can also work locally, but not on the cloud environment, which will fail with the following error

```
Caused by: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.provider(ManagedChannelProvider.java:43) ~[grpc-api-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:353) ~[gax-grpc-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:107) ~[gax-grpc-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:85) ~[gax-grpc-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
```

As I understand, bom should work as a simple version reference for the imported dependencies, should that be equivalent if I simply give consistent version tag for bigquerystorage?

Comment: Did you bundle the transitive dependencies in your deployment artifact?